# Pyspark: create a lag column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, python-datetime

I am using pyspark and obtained a table as below, table_1

```
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+
|  Number|Institution       |       datetime|      date| time|
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+
|AE19075B|               ABC| 7/20/2019 7:45|07/20/2019| 7:45|
|AE11688U|               CBT|2/11/2019 20:31|02/11/2019|20:31|
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+
```

I would like to add a lag column of the time (15 minutes) to the table_1

```
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|  Number|Institution       |       datetime|      date| time|lag1 |
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|AE19075B|               ABC| 7/20/2019 7:45|07/20/2019| 7:45|7:30 |
|AE11688U|               CBT|2/11/2019 20:31|02/11/2019|20:31|20:16|
+--------+------------------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
```

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

table_2 = table_.withColumn('lag1', (datetime.strptime(table1['time'], '%H:%M') -timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M'))
```

The code above could be applied to a string but I have no idea why it cannot apply to the table in this case. It showed an error '''TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Column''', is there any method to obtain a string from a column in Pyspark? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Python functions directly on Spark dataframe columns. You can use Spark SQL functions instead, as shown below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'lag1',
    F.expr("date_format(to_timestamp(time, 'H:m') - interval 15 minute, 'H:m')")
)

df2.show()
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|  Number|Institution|       datetime|      date| time| lag1|
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|AE19075B|        ABC| 7/20/2019 7:45|07/20/2019| 7:45| 7:30|
|AE11688U|        CBT|2/11/2019 20:31|02/11/2019|20:31|20:16|
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
```

Alternatively, you can call the Python function as a UDF (but the performance should be worse than calling Spark SQL functions directly):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

lag = F.udf(lambda t: (datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M') -timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M'))

df2 = df.withColumn('lag1', lag('time'))
df2.show()
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|  Number|Institution|       datetime|      date| time| lag1|
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
|AE19075B|        ABC| 7/20/2019 7:45|07/20/2019| 7:45|07:30|
|AE11688U|        CBT|2/11/2019 20:31|02/11/2019|20:31|20:16|
+--------+-----------+---------------+----------+-----+-----+
```